# About login session

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, authentication

I'm doing my project about developing a website.I'm new to ASP.net and now I have a problem about login session that when a user logged on, everyone who is surfing the web at the same time is also logged as that user no matter they login or not. The session only end when someone click on Logout button and everyone is logged out. Please help me. Every help would be appreciated. 
 Here is my code, I code these thing in my Master page:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)

    {

        string equip = "Equipment.aspx";
        string url = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
        if (url.IndexOf(equip) != -1) { Calendar2.Visible = false; Image1.Visible = false; }
        equip = "Bookings.aspx";
        if (url.IndexOf(equip) != -1) { Calendar2.Visible = false; Image1.Visible = false; }
        equip = "Rooms.aspx";
        if (url.IndexOf(equip) != -1) { Calendar2.Visible = false; Image1.Visible = false; }
        equip = "Users.aspx";
        if (url.IndexOf(equip) != -1) { Calendar2.Visible = false; Image1.Visible = false; }

        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            if (user != "" && user != null)
            {
                loginStatus = true;
                redirectpage = false;

            }
            else
            {

                redirectpage = false;
                loginStatus = false;
                user = "";
                authority = 0;
            }

        }
        else
        {

            if (user == "" || user==null)
            {

                if (cal != null)
                {

                }
                loginStatus = false;
                authority = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                if (cal != null)
                {

                }
                loginStatus = true;
            }
        }
    }

 /// <summary>
 /// Responds to a login request, validating details against the database and
 /// loading the user into the session if successful.
 /// </summary>
 /// <param name="sender">The sending object.</param>
 /// <param name="e">The event arguments.</param>

 protected void Login_Authenticate(object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e)
 {

 SqlConnection oConn =
 new SqlConnection();
 oConn.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=STAVROS\SQLEXPRESS;User ID=sa;Password=123abc;Initial Catalog=webdev";

 sSQL = "select * from tbl_user where username = '" + Login.UserName + "'AND password = '" + Login.Password + "' ";
 SqlCommand oComm1 = new SqlCommand(sSQL, oConn);

 try
 {

 oConn.Open();
 SqlDataReader i = oComm1.ExecuteReader();
 if (i.HasRows)
 {
 while (i.Read())
 {
 user = i.GetString(0);
 authority = i.GetInt16(7);

 loginStatus = true;
 string url = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Absolute…
 string p = "Home.aspx";
 if (url.IndexOf(p) != -1) { Response.Redirect("Home.aspx"); }
 Helper.CreateUserSession(Session, user);
 }

 }
 else
 {
 loginStatus = false;
 Login.FailureText = "Invalid username or password.";
 }


 i.Close();
 }
 catch (Exception ex)
 {
 Response.Redirect("room-book.aspx");

 }

 }

 /// <summary>
 /// Logs the user out (kills the session)
 /// </summary>
 /// <param name="sender">The sender</param>
 /// <param name="e">The event arguments</param>

 protected void btnLogout_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {

 loginStatus = false;
 user = "";
 authority = 0;
 Response.Redirect("Home.aspx");
 }
```

Comment: Post your code for `Helper.CreateUserSession` Something would be fishy there. *Also, you need to check for SQL Injection attacks*

Comment: The only thing that could make this behavior possible was if `loginStatus` were a static field. This is not asp.net authentication. Read the link provided by Jason.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, you have no knowledge of session handling in web-applications.

Here is a [comprehensive tutorial](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/301240) on form based authentication in C# / ASP.NET. You need to read the basic concept before moving ahead.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

loginStatus is field I suppose? If so you must store this flag on per-session basis

Answer (score -2):

It will be better to use Form Authentication Ticket inside your application through Session .Along with that config the Web Config from Windows Authentication to Passport mode authentication.
MoreOver use javascript tag to expire the session inside the form load event at Log Out .